# Getting a variable from a Click event method and using it in another class

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to make a chess board using classes from the first time. Im struggling with getting a variable from the first click event method and use it in the DrawRow method. I know its not finished but im really hung up on this bit and having a hard time continuing

```
private void ToolStripMenuItemDrawBoard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Prevents errors using try catch method
    Graphics paper = pictureBoxDisplay.CreateGraphics();
    try
    {
        int boardSize = int.Parse(ToolStripTextBoxBoardSize.Text);

        if (boardSize > MIN_BOARD_SIZE || boardSize < MAX_BOARD_SIZE)
        {
            DrawRow();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Between 2-10");
            //Clears all textboxes
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    c.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void DrawSquare()
{
    Graphics paper = pictureBoxDisplay.CreateGraphics();
    paper.DrawRectangle(penBlack, positionX, positionY, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public void DrawRow(ToolStripMenuItemDrawBoard_Click(boardSize))
{
    int columnNum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Graphics paper = pictureBoxDisplay.CreateGraphics();
    while (boardSize < columnNum)
    {
        DrawSquare();
        if ((counter % 2) == 0)
            paper.FillRectangle(brDarkBrown, positionX, positionY, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        else if ((counter % 2) != 0)
            paper.FillRectangle(brLightBrown, positionX, positionY, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        positionX = positionX + Width;
        columnNum += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several way to solve this, delegates is one of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

Comment: Sorry i'm confused. You're confused, we are all confused...

Comment: Please confirm which variable you want to acess outside method or class ..there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: I want to get boardSize from ToolStripMenuItemDrawBoard_Click and use it in the DrawRow method

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question looks clear to me. I anyway can't believe it is what you're talking about.

```
private void ToolStripMenuItemDrawBoard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Prevents errors using try catch method
    Graphics paper = pictureBoxDisplay.CreateGraphics();
    try
    {
        int boardSize = int.Parse(ToolStripTextBoxBoardSize.Text);

        if (boardSize > MIN_BOARD_SIZE || boardSize < MAX_BOARD_SIZE)
        {
            // Pass your board size to DrawRow()
            DrawRow(boardSize);
        }
        else
        {
            // ..
        }
    }
}

// Declare your parameter (int boardsize)
public void DrawRow(int boardSize)
{
    // boardSize accessable here
}
```

There you get it. As this got marked I advice you to read through the basics of C#-coding (or general coding).